# Elasticsearch - Give more score for query based on another field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

Consider the next mapping:

```
{
  "properties": {
    ...
    "name": {
      "index": "analyzed",
      "store": "no",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "category_id": {
      "index": "not_analyzed",
      "store": "yes",
      "type": "integer"
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

I want to search by name, but, for the best search relevance, I need to give the higher score for that
items which have most occurrences in the `category_id`.
In other words, if the result of query by `name` shows that most of the items are found in some categories more frequently than in the other categories,
I need to give more score for that items.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You want to boost results in common (frequently-appearing) categories, you mean?

Comment: @AntP yes, that is it